# Wordpress website loading slow

Tags: wordpress

We are currently having our websites developed in WordPress on Windows Server with IIS 8.0, there are 10 websites from which 9 are working fine but only one website is having loading time around 20 seconds due to high TTFB. Our team has tried several options but with no result. Can anyone guide us in the right direction in diagnosing what exactly is causing the issue.

Thanks.

Umesh

Comment: Its depend on your page speed

Comment: Try to make a test in google speed and read with issue come up. There are 1000 things you can do for make your website faster. but before you need to know what make your website slowly.

Comment: Try to test your website using this link
https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/

Comment: you should try to add more information.

Answer (score 2):

### **Reason to slow website:**

- **You’re Running Too Many Plugins**

  Evaluate your current plugins to figure out which ones you actually need.more than 5 years ago and have never been updated.you can check the performance of your plugins with…another plugin. The P3 (Plugin Performance Profiler).
- **Your Homepage Has it All – And Then Some**
- **Your Stunning Images Take Up Too Much Space**

  If you have amazing graphics and an image or two (or more) with every blog post, your loading time will be slower.
- **You’re Using a “Free” Third-Party WordPress Theme**

  There’s an excellent chance that “free” theme comes with a price tag in the form of spyware or viruses, which do more than slow down your site.

**Tools To check performance:**

There is number of but following are most popular,

- PageInsight (Google)
- GTMatrix